# Parse FB Graph API date string into python datetime

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

Here's an example of how the Facebook Graph API is returning date strings for me:

2011-03-06T03:36:45+0000

how would I parse this into a python datetime class?  I'm aware of the datetime.strptime function, which takes in a second parameter that contains some googly-eyed format string, but don't know which letters and dashes to include.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here it is with time & [strptime](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime):

```
>>> time.strptime('2011-03-06T03:36:45+0000', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000')
time.struct_time(tm_year=2011, tm_mon=3, tm_mday=6, tm_hour=3, tm_min=36, tm_sec=45, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=65, tm_isdst=-1)
```

or with datetime:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2011-03-06T03:36:45+0000','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000')
```

As you see it returns the time_struct with the fields correctly filled out.

Here is a translation of the format:

- %Y = year with century (2011)
- %m = month w/ leading zero
- %d = day w/ leading zero
- %H = hour w/ leading zero, 24-hour clock
- %M = minute
- %S = second
- T, -, and : are used as delimiters, and included as literal strings
- +0000 is again included as a literal string

Comment: This worked brilliantly... thanks for catering to my laziness :)

Comment: No problem... this time haha. Figured a quick writeup like this might be what others are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [10]: datetime.datetime.strptime('2011-03-06T03:36:45+0000','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000')

Out[10]: datetime.datetime(2011, 3, 6, 3, 36, 45)
```